# How to express 5 sets of data currently in one column 5 different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle10g

My current table looks like this

| CPNT_ID | Org_Id | Stud ID | Compl_Dte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trainee | Org001 | 101010 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| SvcTech | Org001 | 101010 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| CrewChief | Org001 | 101010 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| Trainee | Org001 | 101013 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| SvcTech | Org001 | 101013 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| Trainee | Org002 | 101011 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| SvcTech | Org002 | 101011 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| Trainee | Org002 | 101012 | Nov 13, 2016 |

This works if im looking at one organization, but if i need to see multiple organizations I need the table to look like this. I don't have enough reputation to chat

| Organization | Trainee | SvcTech | CrewChief | SvcCoord | Appr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Org001 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Org002 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This is my code

```
select 
cpnt.cpnt_id,
s.ORG_ID,
pc.stud_id,
pc.compl_dte
from 
        pa_stud_program sp,
        pa_program p,
        pa_student s,
        pa_stud_cpnt pc,
        ps_program_type pt,
        pa_cpnt cpnt
WHERE p.PROGRAM_SYS_GUID = sp.PROGRAM_SYS_GUID
    and pc.compl_dte is not null
    and cpnt.cpnt_id in ('Trainee','SvcTech','CrewChief','SvcCoord','Appr')
    and s.jp_id in ('1801','1805','1810','1811')
    and s.EMP_STAT_ID = 'Active'
    AND cpnt.CPNT_TYP_ID     = p.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND cpnt.CPNT_ID         = p.CPNT_ID
    AND cpnt.REV_DTE         = p.REV_DTE
    AND pc.STUD_ID           = sp.STUD_ID
    AND sp.stud_id           = s.STUD_ID
    AND pc.CPNT_ID           = sp.CPNT_ID
    AND pc.CPNT_TYP_ID       = sp.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND pc.REV_DTE           = sp.REV_DTE
    AND pc.seq_num           = sp.seq_num
    AND pt.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID   = p.PROGRAM_TYPE   
    /** and s.PERSON_ID_EXTERNAL  in [UserSearch]*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query you posted doesn't match sample data; there's no `organization` there.

Anyway: this is the principle you should use. Apply it to code that actually returns data you posted.

```
SQL> with test (org, program, unique_users) as
  2    (select 'Store 1', 'Trainee',  1 from dual union all
  3     select 'Store 1', 'SvcTech', 12 from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select 'Store 2', 'Trainee',  2 from dual union all
  6     select 'Store 2', 'Appr'   , 11 from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 'Store 3', 'SvcTech' ,  2 from dual union all
  9     select 'Store 3', 'CrewChief', 1 from dual union all
 10     select 'Store 3', 'SvcCoord' , 5 from dual
 11    )
 12  select org,
 13    max(case when program = 'Trainee'   then unique_users end) trainee,
 14    max(case when program = 'SvcTech'   then unique_users end) svctech,
 15    max(case when program = 'CrewChief' then unique_users end) crewchief,
 16    max(case when program = 'SvcCoord'  then unique_users end) svccoord,
 17    max(case when program = 'Appr'      then unique_users end) appr
 18  from test
 19  group by org
 20  order by org;

ORG        TRAINEE    SVCTECH  CREWCHIEF   SVCCOORD       APPR
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Store 1          1         12
Store 2          2                                          11
Store 3                     2          1          5

SQL>
```

Comment: let me fix my original post

Comment: Don't. Just apply what I showed you.